# Method of Checking Integrity of Data and Managing Data Reliably

Tags: usb-storage

II have important data that I would like to store offline with occasional addition. But, when data is stored offline, there is a possibility that the data may become corrupt and I may not even know it. So question 1 is, how concerned should I be for this kind of corruption?

Now, suppose I should be concerned enough that I have multiple copies of data. I feel I should, on regular intervals, check whether the data maintained is still valid. Question 2: Generally how long should the intervals be? If they depend on the drive I use, then assume I am using flash based storage (SSD or Flash).

So, now I have to check the data, and determine if it is valid. A good way to do this is to use hashes and verify integrity. I can do this on my own for myself using whatever scripts I want. But, the point is, I want this model to work for my parents. (My parents run Ubuntu, so they have some tech know how, but I cannot expect them to dig into command line.)

**Is there a GUI-based method of checking the integrity of data on multiple USB storage devices and then correct and repair the files by copying the correct one (if needed, and if it can)?**

I may finally go with an interactive script, but if a GUI exists for now, it will be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are being *way* to overly concerned about data corruption.  The data on your PC is *FAR* more  likely to get corrupted than on a USB flash drive.  Flash media is extremely reliable and you should have no concerns about data loss.

I am more concerned about you keeping all your passwords on a flash drive that could be easily lost or stolen.  It would be far safer to keep your passwords using a program like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) which can create an encrypted file that you can store in the cloud on a service like DropBox.  This would allow you safe and secure access to your data from anywhere without the possibility of losing a USB drive.  If you *had* to, you could store the encrypted file on the USB drive, but why risk losing it?

Comment: I already use KeePassX. But KeePassX is limited in terms of data I can store and its format. But you are right, I can tar up and AESCrypt my text files and do the same to that.